# Return a Stream and write it to disk?

Tags: c#, stream

I have an ASP.Net Web API project that is returning a response `HttpResponseMessage`, I'm setting the content of that message to a `StreamContent` that has been initialized with a `Stream`

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, channelId);            
response.Content = new StreamContent(myStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")

return response;
```

I'm trying to some rudimentary local caching of the file represented by the stream, can I both return the stream and write it to disk without having to wait for it to finish writing it to disk before returning it to the requester?

Alternate method I'm considering would be to have a queue of files to load into my local cache and add the id of the requested file to the queue then send the stream back as a response.  Then have a separate worker process the queue so that file can be retrieved from my local cache next time.

Comment: Would writing the stream to disk in a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) and then returning not work for you?

Comment: I guess that's my question what happens if I start reading the stream on in the Task thread while at the same time sending that stream to the client to be read there?  Seems like 2 processes reading a stream can't end well.  I think the queue is the right answer, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.